# .NET Core - Dependency Injection into earlier declared Service?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

.NET Core MVC 6,

I want to use a Service2 inside another Service1, which is declared before Service2. Also, the method where I want to use it is overriding SaveChanges(), so no Method Injection.

ie.:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
.....
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
....

class MyDbContext(){
 public override  Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)){
//use stuff from AccountService
}
}
```

AccountService is using the Context too.

So, how can I now use methods from AccountService inside MyDbContext, when MyDbContext is declared first?

Comment: Why are you overriding `SaveChanges` and why does the method use a higher-level abstraction like an account service? That's the root of the problem. If you really need to do extra work while saving, eg to audit changes, use a [SaveChanges interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#savechanges-interception)

Comment: With the information posted here one can only say this is the wrong way around. You'll have to post the actual code that uses `AccountService` if you want people to help with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a misunderstanding about the order in which .net core runs. When you run the code, your service will be registered first, the order of registration does not matter. What is really affected by the order is the middleware.

According to your code, you want to override the `SaveChangesAsync` method, then you should use EF Core to perform corresponding database operations, right? You can inject `IAccountService` in the constructor of `MyDbContext`.

Of course, since you are injecting `IAccountService` in `MyDbContext` and at the same time injecting `MyDbContext` in `AccountService`, this will cause a circular dependency.

A simple way is to use `Lazy<T>` class which is based on this [blog](https://thomaslevesque.com/2020/03/18/lazily-resolving-services-to-fix-circular-dependencies-in-net-core/):

Custom extension method:

```
public static class LazyResolutionMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddLazyResolution(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services.AddTransient(
            typeof(Lazy<>),
            typeof(LazilyResolved<>));
    }
}

public class LazilyResolved<T> : Lazy<T>
{
    public LazilyResolved(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>)
    {
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcMovieContext")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
builder.Services.AddLazyResolution();
```

AccountService:

```
public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    private Lazy<MyDbContext> _context;
    public AccountService(Lazy<MyDbContext> context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public string Test(string testString)
    {
        return "success"; 
    }
}

public interface IAccountService
{
    string Test(string testString);
}
```

MyDbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private Lazy<IAccountService> _accountService;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, Lazy<IAccountService> accountService)
        : base(options)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        var testString = _accountService.Value.Test("test");
        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        return result;
    }
    //...
}
```

When I call `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`:

[image]

So what does `no Method Injection` mean?